# Is 'It was never mentioned/explained' a valid answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-quality, accepted-answer

Fans will often be curious or even obsess over tiny details and minutiae that the creators of whatever we are fan of never gave an explanation to, whether it was in-universe or out-of-universe, for any number of reasons.

As an example, I'm thinking of an interview with Mickael Okuda where a journalist asked him *'How do the Heinsenberg compensator works?'* and he replied *'They work just fine, thank you.'*

We know why the showrunners created this bit of technology, to go around the Heinsenberg Uncertainty Principle, but we do not know how it does it, because it was never explained. And we couldn't even guess an answer since it does not work according to currently known laws of physics, and guessing isn't really what this site is for anyway.

So, when there is no answer, is replying with *'It was never mentioned/explained'* a valid answer?

Comment: If you ask the creator and they say "Dunno", then that's a really good answer.

Comment: It's true that in this day an age, it's way easier to ask the authors/creators directly.

Comment: What's the alternative? Leave the question with no answers? Don't allow the questions in the first place?

Comment: I think this question is salvageable if you changed it to something like "***Is it OK to post an answer that says that even the creator doesn't know"***

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it would still feel like a duplicate. I think the answer by Rand al'thor in the duplicate question does answer the question as a whole.